# Microsoft Dynamics 2015 Workflow is triggering when fields not selected in record fields change are updated.

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I have a workflow created to trigger a task when record fields are changed on an entity. Tasks are being created even when fields not check are updated. Why is the workflow sending for fields not selected? Thank you!

Comment: Hey, it's been 7 years but I'm encountering this issue when a call is made from a server using httpClient or CRM SDK but works fine in javascript. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds unlikely, is there some way you can verify it? I don't know exactly how that could be done, perhaps by turning on the auditing to see that the fields really aren't touched. Is it a real time workflow or an asynchronous one? If it's async, can you save the workflows so you can see how they are run?

Regards